# MongoDB: Best way to find different documents with their respective maximum values

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents in my DB in the collection `animals`:

```
{ "animal": "dog", "age": 1}
{ "animal": "dog", "age": 2}
{ "animal": "dog", "age": 3}

{ "animal": "cat", "age": 1}
{ "animal": "cat", "age": 4}

{ "animal": "rabbit", "age": 9}
```

How do I return a result so that I get both dogs, cats and rabbits with the max age. Example:

```
[
    { "animal": "dog", "age": 3},    # oldest dog in DB
    { "animal": "cat", "age": 4},    # oldest cat in DB
    { "animal": "rabbit", "age": 9}  # oldest rabbit in DB

]
```

I am trying to use the `$max` operator in mongoDB but not sure about using that for different kinds of animals and filtering their age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's documentation on [aggregation using the `$max` and `$group` operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#examples) should help you here. Basically, the `$group` operator will allow you to group the documents by the `animal` key, and then `$max` will allow you to query for the max `age` within each group.

Here's the query:

```js
db.animals.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$animal",
           maxAge: { $max: "$age" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

which should give you the result:

```
    [
       { "_id": "dog", "maxAge": 3},  
       { "_id": "cat", "maxAge": 4},    
       { "_id": "rabbit", "maxAge": 9} 
    ]
```

Comment: How do I see "animal" key instead of "_id" in results?

Comment: @summerNight:  The results of the `$group` operator will always contain the value of the group in the `_id` field. I think you could also add the `animal` field to the results: one way to do this might be to add `animal : { $last: "$animal" }` to the query. This will add the key `animal` to each result document, and populate it with the value for "animal" seen in the last document in the group. (For more info see the [documentation on grouping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/))